# Prove that sgn(cA) = sgn(c)sgn(A) for all nonzero real scalars.

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

> **Definition**: Suppose $A\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ has no eigenvalues on the imaginary axis and let $S = $ sgn(A). Where $$\text{sgn}(A) :=X\left[\begin{matrix}-I & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{matrix}\right]X^{-1}.$$
> and $$X^{-1}AX = \left[\begin{matrix}N & 0 \\ 0 & P\end{matrix}\right]$$
> is the Jordan Canonical form for $A$, with $N$ containing all Jordan blocks corresponding to eigenvalues of $A$ in the left half-plane and $P$ containing all Jordan blocks corresponding to eigenvalues in the right half-plane. Furthermore, the dimensions of $-I$ and $I$ are the same as $N$ and $P$, respectively.

> Prove that sgn(cA) = sgn(c)sgn(A) for all nonzero real scalars $c$.

I am not quite sure how to prove this. Any help is great! Thanks!

Comment: Apparently the dimensions of $-I$ and $I$ are the same as those of $N$ and $P$, respectively. Or is it not?

Comment: Yes @kabenyuk. Sorry I forgot to include that in the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints.

1. Your formula is sufficient to check for $c=-1$.
2. Let $J$ be a matrix such that
   $J^{-1}\operatorname{diag}(N,P)J=\operatorname{diag}(P,N)$.
3. Let $Y=XJ$. Then we get
   $$
   Y^{-1}(-A)Y=\operatorname{diag}(-P,-N).
   $$
4. Moreover, if $N$ is a matrix of size $n$ and
   $P$ is a matrix of size $p$, then we have
   $$
   J^{-1}\operatorname{diag}(-I_n,I_p)J=\operatorname{diag}(I_p,-I_n)\Rightarrow
   J\operatorname{diag}(I_p,-I_n)J^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(-I_n,I_p),
   $$
   where $I_k$ is the identity matrix of size $k$.
5. Finally,
   $$
   \operatorname{sgn}(-A)=Y\operatorname{diag}(-I_p,I_n)Y^{-1}=
   -X\operatorname{diag}(-I_n,I_p)X^{-1}=-\operatorname{sgn}(A)
   $$